# Trying to print the stem (basename w/o extension) from a glob list

Tags: python, pycharm, glob, pathlib

I'm trying to print the stem-only of each file in a glob list.  The filenames are the names of people so I would like to just display their names without full path and extension.  Any suggestions? I have looked at os.path but the pathlib.stem seemed the cleanest.

```
    def listknownfaces(self, instance):
        faceslist = glob.glob('Event_Faces/*.jpg')
        print(faceslist)
        for one_item in faceslist.glob('*.jpg'):
            print(one_item.stem)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention `pathlib.Path.stem`. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathlib` to [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and then get the stem. [`pathlib.Path.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) gives you the name of the file without the extension.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("Event_Faces")
for path in p.glob("*.jpg"):
    print(path.stem)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Did the job!

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, please select it as the correct answer by clicking the green check mark.